# SQLite in Android can't delete row with multiple where clauses

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Ok, so I'm trying to make my database delete an entire row if two conditions are fulfilled. I've tried using the `delete(String tableName, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)` method as provided from the SDK

However, a row is deleted only if I put in ONE where clause, such as this:

`mDatabase.delete(ItemTable.NAME, ItemTable.cols.NAME + " = ?",
                  new String[] {latestItem.getName()});`

Wherein attempting to put in multiple WHERE clauses breaks the whole thing

`mDatabase.delete(ItemTable.NAME,
                  ItemTable.cols.NAME + " = ? AND " +
                  ItemTable.cols.PRICE + " = ?",
                  new String[] {latestItem.getName(), 
                  String.valueOf(latestItem.getPrice())});`

I am completely out of ideas on how to tackle this. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause (if any) is always **ONE**. You may add more conditions to it. Your conditions are probably not both true at the same time.

Comment: @MD Well, I have no holyday ever, since I'm on my own. So, dividing myself between Android programming and studying Blender 3D. You may see my recent 3D works on FB.

Comment: @Rotwang Awesome. I wish I could be like you.

Comment: @user4442318 Please show some sample data from your database that exhibits this behavior (where both conditions together does not delete the row, but either condition by itself does delete the row).

Comment: Does `mDatabase.delete(ItemTable.NAME, ItemTable.cols.PRICE + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(latestItem.getprice())});` work as well? (i.e. exclude the second argument being the lause as opposed to two args)

Comment: What is the type of the price, in your app and in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I figured out what was wrong.

Turns out the condition for checking the item name was returning TRUE but the item price condition wasn't. Apparently there was a mismatch with the sqlite data affinity of the `itemprice()` data.

I fixed this by forcing all column data affinities to be TEXT and storing my item price as a String through `String.valueOf(getItemprice())`. Everything works this way.

Thanks though for all your help!